# Issue while rendering OpenAPI spec json in terraform rest api gateway resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I wanted to pass some variables while rendering the json file of OpenAPI spec through the template file but it shows the below changes.

Code:
resource.tf

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "default" {
body = jsonencode(var.routes)
  name = "dev-api-gateway-fargate"
  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
 module "api_gateway_new" {
   source = "../../../modules/api-gateway/new/"
    routes = templatefile("${path.module}/routes.tpl",{
      url = "https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json"
    }
    )
}
```

Terraform Plan

```
~ resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "default" {
      ~ body                         = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              - info    = {
                  - title   = "example"
                  - version = "1.0"
                }
              - openapi = "3.0.1"
              - paths   = {
                  - "/path1" = {
                      - get = {
                          - x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
                              - httpMethod           = "GET"
                              - payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
                              - type                 = "HTTP_PROXY"
                              - uri                  = "https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } -> <<-EOT
                {
                  openapi = "3.0.1"
                  info = {
                    title   = var.rest_api_name
                    version = "1.0"
                  }
                  paths = {
                    "/v1/alerts" = {
                      get = {
                        x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
                          httpMethod           = "GET"
                          payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
                          type                 = "HTTP_PROXY"
                          uri                  = "https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
            EOT
        )
        id                           = "mxktrgeypg"
        name                         = "dev-api-gateway-fargate"
        tags                         = {}
        # (10 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }
```

routes.tpl

```
                {
                  openapi = "3.0.1"
                  info = {
                    title   = var.rest_api_name
                    version = "1.0"
                  }
                  paths = {
                    "/v1/alerts" = {
                      get = {
                        x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
                          httpMethod           = "GET"
                          payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
                          type                 = "HTTP_PROXY"
                          uri                  = "${url}"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: No error with this example. But it is trying to change. However the content is same but passed via templatefile in this case.

Comment: So, the title of the question is wrong, as there are no errors, right? Also, would you mind adding `routes.tpl` to the question?

Comment: It is the same as it is shown in the output. Tried different methods to render it sometimes applied worked but with an error saying that the wrong open API format.

Comment: Ah, ok, the template has an error. You cannot use variables in that way inside of the template files. I will try to add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the template file as it seems you were trying to add a name for the API but you provided `var.rest_api_name` which is treated as a literal. In order to fix this, there are two changes that need to take place, one in the module call and one in the template file itself.

```
module "api_gateway_new" {
 source = "../../../modules/api-gateway/new/"
 routes = templatefile("${path.module}/routes.tpl",{
           url = "https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json",
           name = var.rest_api_name
          }
        )
}
```

Then, in the template file:

```
{
    openapi = "3.0.1"
    info = {
    title   = "${name}" # this has changed
    version = "1.0"
    }
    paths = {
    "/v1/alerts" = {
        get = {
        x-amazon-apigateway-integration = {
            httpMethod           = "GET"
            payloadFormatVersion = "1.0"
            type                 = "HTTP_PROXY"
            uri                  = "${url}"
      }
     }
    }
   }
}
```

Since the template file is almost JSON formatted already, I would suggest changing the file to look like this:

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
      "title": "${name}",
      "version": "1.0"
    },
    "paths": {
      "/v1/alerts": {
        "get": {
          "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "payloadFormatVersion": "1.0",
            "type": "HTTP_PROXY",
            "uri": "${url}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And then you can drop the `jsonencode` form the module code:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "default" {
  body = var.routes
  name = "dev-api-gateway-fargate"

  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
}
```

Also, this should work for creating an OpenAPI spec, but the validation of this code says it is missing a `responses` section. So for the sake of testing if it works, you could add the `responses`:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "${name}",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/v1/alerts": {
      "get": {
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "200 response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/Empty"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
          "httpMethod": "GET",
          "payloadFormatVersion": "1.0",
          "type": "HTTP_PROXY",
          "uri": "${url}"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Empty": {
        "title": "Empty Schema",
        "type": "object"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have used [1] to validate the OpenAPI spec, so if it is still complaining, the tool should give you a pretty good idea of what is missing/wrong.

---

[1] https://apitools.dev/swagger-parser/online/